# Minimum working code for QtWebEngine evaluating JavaScript, disabling chrome sandbox

Tags: javascript, chromium, qtwebengine

I am trying to create a minimal POC of evaluating javascript using using QtWebEngine and no GUI involved.

One attempt

```
int main(void)
{
  int argc = 1;
  char *argv[] = {"Hello"};

  QApplication app(argc, argv);;    

  QtWebEngine *e = QtWebEngine::initialize()
  QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage;
  page->runJavaScript("'Java''' 'Script'",
              [](const QVariant &result){ qDebug() << result; });

  std::cout << "Compiled and Linked" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but this errored with a display not attached error, something to do with guis I take it.

I also found something about the distinction of console app and gui app, but it was not clear to me and I tried using variantions of

```
  QCoreApplication *app = QCoreApplication::instance();
```

but this also erred. 
I also ran into the issue of

```
  :[0712/072409:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the
  SUID sandbox! See
  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md
  for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
```

and apparently --disable-setuid-sandbox to chromium is an escape hatch                                   but I'm not quite clear where I could set that programmatically.

Comment: I got an example working and will post soon.

Comment: Use the option `--no-sandbox` instead. See: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49995